# DMR code plug for Anytone d878uv

Tags: united-states, dmr, anytone

Just moved from SoCal and there were sites out there for exchanging code plugs for the Anytone 878uv.  I was wondering if there are similar sites for the northeast of the US.  I would love to get a basic set to start the process.

Comment: Hi Paul, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a web search for "new york code plugs" and found a bunch from various sites:

- [N2CID Digital Repeater Network](http://www.cidcomm.com/codeplugs/)
- [Hudson Valley Digital Network](https://hvdn.org/%2B-dmr-code-plugs) no Anytone plugs yet
- [BridgeCom Systems](https://www.bridgecomsystems.com/pages/new-york)

I also found some for surrounding areas:

- [New England Digital Emergency Communications Network](https://nedecn.org/downloads/codeplugs/)
- [Frederick Amateur Radio Club](https://frederickarc.org/codeplugs/) in Frederick, Maryland

Your local ham club can probably hook you up with some.  Make your own and share!

Comment: Thank you for marking my answer as accepted with the green check mark.  If you like my answer, please also upvote it.  By the way, you're often better off not marking any answer as accepted for a while, in the hope of attracting more answers.  I've waited as long as two days.